# refreshing just one entitiy in Entitiy Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is it possible to refresh only one entity (which depends on one table) in entity framework 4.0 designer? 
when I refresh model from sql server database, it refreshes all entities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't refresh only one entity at a time with the update model from database wizard.

You can make a backup of your edmx, update it, open it as an xml file (right click>Open With>XML (Text) Editor), copy the modified sections about your entity (in the csdl, msl and ssdl sections), and paste them in your backup.

Comment: Thanks, fair enough. But I would prefer not to do. seemed to me very risky  :)

Comment: Well, contrary to what MS could let you think, you can't do everything through the designer, so you'll eventually have to open the xml ;)